# Stateful behaviour with guest exe on service fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a guest exe where it expects folder name to be passed during startup, which it then uses as a "working" directory for writing data, logs etc.

If I wanted to host this exe in service fabric and make it reliable and stateful do I just pass the exe a UNC path to a common location where it would write to no matter which VM the instance was running on ?
Or are there better ways of managing this ?

Answer (score 1):

That should work. Do make sure to replicate/back-up the contents of the common drive. When using multiple service instances you'll likely need to deal with file locking.

And see if it's worth the effort (or even possible) to change the application to start using the SDK, and create a genuine reliable Stateful Service from it. That'll provide you with transactions, concurrency control and data replication by default.

Comment: Sorry you lost me on the second part of your answer. Do you mean bin the exe and write my own reliable stateful service that does exactly what the exe does ? Not possible. The exe uses a com component that does all the r/w.

Comment: I did mean that. You don't own the COM component code?

Comment: No not in this instance.